# Track all IDs and CLASS in CSS do have any particular selector by jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I do have a small problem. Actually i want to track all classes or IDs do have any particular selector applied in CSS by jQuery or JavaScript.

For example:

**CSS**

```
.even:nth-child(2n) {
 /* declarations goes here */
}
```

Now i do want to target all classes or Ids do have "nth-child" applied in CSS and get it's all declarations, so that i can apply it by jQuery in non-supporting browsers.

It can be any selector like 'nth-child', '>', '~'.

I Know we do have many libraries like selectivizr do that for us but i want to do something without using any libraries.

Comment: so if you wanted to make them all bold would $('class^=nth-child :even').css('font:bold'); work?

Comment: So basically you are inventing your own library... I really recommend to use an existing one if your only criterium for not using one is that you don't *want* to.

Comment: @FelixKling I am not saying that i am trying to invent my library, i just want to write it my self. Because i need thousands of different things in my application and i can't use different libraries for all of them. That's why i try to use only basic libraries like jQuery and try to write my code myself.